# gzip file reading error (probably php or nginx issue)

Tags: nginx, gzip, zlib

I am uploading gzip files in two different servers, one runs PHP 5.4 using Apache2 (ipage.com) and the other one runs PHP 5.5 using Nginx 1.8.1 on (Webuzo).

- When I am requesting for the file using **Firefox 44** browser, the
  file is displaying its contents if requested from the server running
  on Apache2 (ipage.com) and is offering download while requesting from
  the nginx server.
- The second problem is that PHP running on [HHVM](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00UMYTMDK/ref=srh_res_product_title?ie=UTF8&sr=0-4&qid=1458540824243) (Hip Hop virtual
  machine) is failing to read the file from the Nginx server (Webuzo) but is
  reading the same file nicely from the Apache2 (ipage.com) server.

I am absolutely clueless on what exactly is making the difference as its the same file just on different servers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that all your headers are correct on both servers in particular Accept-Encoding for gzip needs to be supported by both Servers. Before trying to serve a pre-gzipped file server a plain text one first.

Comment: I already checked *Accept-Encoding* using phpinfo and they are identical.

Comment: Could you please tell me where else should I check to find out the problem? I have checked the entries in the *nginx.conf* file.